# DOCX file to text file conversion using Python

Tags: python, file-conversion, python-docx

I wrote the following code to convert my docx file to text file. The output that I get printed in my text file is the last paragraph/part of the whole file and not the complete content. The code is as follows:

```
from docx import Document
import io
import shutil

def convertDocxToText(path):
    for d in os.listdir(path):
        fileExtension=d.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension =="docx":
            docxFilename = path + d
            print(docxFilename)
            document = Document(docxFilename)


# for printing the complete document
            print('\nThe whole content of the document:->>>\n')
            for para in document.paragraphs:
                textFilename = path + d.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
                with io.open(textFilename,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:
                    #textFile.write(unicode(para.text))
                    x=unicode(para.text)
                    print(x) //the complete content gets printed by this line
                    textFile.write((x)) #after writing the content to text file only last paragraph is copied.
                #textFile.write(para.text)

path= "/home/python/resumes/"
convertDocxToText(path)
```

Comment: `with io.open(textFilename,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:` is _inside_ your `for para in document.paragraphs:` loop. This means you keep opening the file on each iteration in write-mode, wiping any existing content. You need to open the file once before running your loop i.e. put the `for` loop inside the `with` block, not the other way round.

Comment: thanks i made the changes and it worked..

Comment: @sharayusalunkhe is this code currently working for you ?, mine is giving errors even with the corrections,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

as your code says in the last `for` loop:

```
        for para in document.paragraphs:
            textFilename = path + d.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
            with io.open(textFilename,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:
                x=unicode(para.text)
                textFile.write((x))
```

for each paragraph in whole document, you try to open a file named `textFilename` so let's say you have a file named `MyFile.docx` in `/home/python/resumes/` so the `textFilename` value that contains the path will be `/home/python/resumes/MyFile.txt` always in whole of `for` loop, so the problem is that you open the same file in `w` mode which is a `Write` mode, and will overwrite the whole file content.

#### Solution:

you must open the file once out of that for loop then try add paragraphs one by one to it.

Answer (score 3):

the following is the solution for the above problem:

```
from docx import Document
import io
import shutil
import os

def convertDocxToText(path):
    for d in os.listdir(path):
        fileExtension=d.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension =="docx":
            docxFilename = path + d
            print(docxFilename)
            document = Document(docxFilename)
            textFilename = path + d.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
            with io.open(textFilename,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:
                for para in document.paragraphs: 
                    textFile.write(unicode(para.text))

path= "/home/python/resumes/"
convertDocxToText(path)
```