# how to change doc to txt by python in centos

Tags: python, linux, centos

I want to change doc file to text file by using python in Centos 7. How can I do it?

I tried to use os.system(libreoffice) but it was so slow. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719258/docx-file-to-text-file-conversion-using-python

Comment: @eraul Thanks, I have already done with docx file. But I have no ideas about .doc file.

Answer (score 0):

Another method without libreoffice: https://gist.github.com/bufke/8798262
And antiword should be installed.