# How to Retrieve a particular section from docx file using python docx2txt module

Tags: python

I am using python **docx2txt** module to work with docx files.Now i am able to get the entire document by using this module.But my requirement is to retrieve document section by section(like heading with its contents alone).Please help me to get a particular section or headings by using docx2txt library.

Answer (score 0):

The `docx2text` module has no built-in function for that.

That means you have a couple of options.

- Try to recognize section headers and sections from the converted text. This will probably be difficult because it is hard to distinguish a one-sentence paragraph from a section header.
- Open the `docx` file using the `zipfile` module. Then read the `word/document.xml` file from the zipfile and extract the information. This will give you the complete XML structure, so it should be possible to recognize section headers.
- Use `python-docx`, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719258/docx-file-to-text-file-conversion-using-python).

All computerized processing requires that the documents have a *consistent* internal structure. If you have a document that uses real section headers *but also* formatted lines to start a section, your conversion is bound to fail.